# What does the expression: "Du kannst mich mal" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase, informal

I want to know what this sentence means:

> Du kannst mich mal.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please [edit] your question to provide some context and state what you found and understood so far, e.g., why did a dictionary not help you? This site is neither willing nor suited to replace a dictionary, but that’s all we can do in response to your question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft In *this* case, I disagree. On the surface, yes, the OP could try a dictionary, but "you can me" isn't particularly helpful, is it? I'd suggest an edit instead. (Happy to do it, but later.)

Comment: @Stephie: Good dictionaries do contain phrases: [1](http://www.dict.cc/?s=du%20kannst%20mich%20mal&=DEEN), [2](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/du%20kannst%20mich%20mal). (Anyway, if there is some disagreement I will reöpen, so the community can decide.)

Answer (score 7):

It is a short version of

> Du kannst mich mal am Arsch lecken.

Literally:

> You can lick me at my ass.

In English you would say:

> Kiss my ass.

**Maybe interesting to know:**

In previous times, German speaking people did not lick **at** the ass, but **in** the ass:

> Leck mich **im** Arsch.

Two famous quotes:

1. Johann Wolfgang von Goethe wrote this lines in the third act of his stage play »Götz von Berlechingen«:

   > *Götz*: Mich ergeben! Auf Gnad und Ungnad! Mit wem redet Ihr! Bin ich ein Räuber! Sag deinem Hauptmann: Vor Ihro Kayserliche Majestät, hab ich, wie immer schuldigen Respect. Er aber, sags ihm, **er kann mich im Arsch lecken.**
   >
   > *Götz*: Surrender? To grace and disgrace? Who are you talking to? Am I a robber? Tell your captain: I, as always, properly respect your imperial majesty. But he, tell him this, **he can lick me in the ass.**
2. Here, on Youtube, is a canon in six voices from Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart about licking in the ass: [»Leck mich im Arsch« on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9MN2WeqFY8)

   Read more about this canon on Wikipedia: [»Leck mich im Arsch« on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leck_mich_im_Arsch)

Answer (score 3):

It's a shortened variety of the [Swabian salute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swabian_salute). ("Kiss my arse.") It comes in many varieties, sometimes omitting parts, sometimes changing words to "hide" the offensive bits - while the listener clearly understands the meaning.

A frequent version is your *Du kannst mich <del>mal am Arsch lecken</del>!* and it's so standard, that even the beginning is clearly recognized without saying the "offending" parts aloud.

Comment: Interesting trivia: Even if his saying is today called the *Swabian salute*, Götz would most probably have considered himself a Franconian. History always seems to get it wrong ;)